# Flask, SQLAlchemy : KeyError: 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, runtime-error, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to follow the instructions from the following tutorial:

[Tutorial](https://medium.com/@rodkey/deploying-a-flask-application-on-aws-a72daba6bb80)

I downloaded the code from the following repo:

[Repo](https://github.com/inkjet/flask-aws-tutorial)

However when I run it locally and try to add something to the database, I get the following error:

```
builtins.KeyError
KeyError: 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'
```

When I tried to read the traceback, I realised that even if I add a variable SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS to the config file, some python library file is unable to recognise it exists.

Looks like there is another answer to a similar question, but that was more like a quick fix, not why this is happening.

I would like to know why this is happening and how to fix it.Preferably without changing the whole structure.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 34):

Having two `app = Flask(__name__)` in the code can cause this problem.

That was my case, I removed one and kept the one in the app's folder's `__init__.py`, and it worked

Comment: Another reason for this error is forgetting the 
db.init_app(app)

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem by this way.
Remove the current one, and replace the old version.

```
pip3 uninstall flask-sqlalchemy
pip3 install flask-sqlalchemy==2.1.0
```

Comment: Wow. That worked like a charm. Never expected that changing the version would do such a wonder. Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this solution. We are now on version 2.4.1 and this issue exists in scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

@Javier's answer gave me a direction to problem as mentioned reason of error is having multiple flask apps.

Apart from creating app in `__init__.py` one more solution which worked was to use newly created app's context to run the query and **boom!!!** error was gone.

Below is code snippet for using newly created app's context:-

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('./config.py')
init_app(app)

def create():
    with app.app_context():
       #Below Tags is model class 
       tag = Tags(**data)
       db.session.add(tag)
       db.session.commit()
       return from_sql(tag)
```

Comment: Where is `config.py` ? please add it there

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem .. i am using connexion

The solution which worked for me was removing one instance of connexion object in server.py. You need to init connex_app in the config file then load the object in server like this:

in my config.py

```
connex_app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir=basedir)
```

and in my server.py

```
import config

connex_app = config.connex_app
```

This way using the object which is already instantiated worked for me !!!