# Unable to connect to sqlite database from flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to take username as the input from form and add it to sqlite database. But i'm not able to connect to sqlite. I'm using FLASK.
My code is as follows:

config.py

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config(object):
    # ...
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')
                                # os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from app import  models
```

models.py

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.orm import column_property
import datetime

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Username = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)
```

login.html

```
{% extends 'layouts.html' %}
{% block title %}Loimg{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<p>Welcome back, {{ username }}!</p>
        <h1>Tell us your name!!!</h1>
        <div class="login">
            <form action="{{url_for('login')}}" method="post">
                <span class = "text">Your Name </span> <input class="uname" id = "username" type="text" name="username">  <br/><br><br>        
                <div class="msg">{{msg}}</div>
                <input class = "button"  type="submit"  value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>       
{% endblock %}
```

main.py

```
from flask import *
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy  
from config import Config
from app import db
from app.models import User, FileDetails, UserFileMapping

app = Flask(__name__) 
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "random string"

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello world"

@app.route('/login',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def login():

    if request.method =='POST' and 'username' in request.form:
        username = request.form['username']
        try:
            newUser = User(Username=username) 
            db.session.add(newUser)
            # return "session started"
            if db.session.commit():
                return ("added user")

        except:
            return "cant add"
        # return redirect(url_for('upload')
    return render_template ("login.html")
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app.run(debug = True)
```

initially i ran

```
flask db init
flask db migrate
flask db upgrade
```

It is catching the exception and printing "cant add". I dont know why db.session.add(Username = username) is not working.

Error:
[image]
  Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Remove try/except block and show the exception trace.

Comment: can you add what error you are getting?

Comment: KeyError: 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS' at db.session.add(newUser)

Comment: Please provide the traceback as text, not a screenshot. It is for example cut in the screenshot, so we don't have all the details. It looks like you have two `app = Flask(__name__)` in different modules, why is that?

Comment: I suspect that your issue is the 2 separate `app` instances, or having not called `db.init_app`, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274152/flask-sqlalchemy-keyerror-sqlalchemy-track-modifications

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask, SQLAlchemy : KeyError: 'SQLALCHEMY\_TRACK\_MODIFICATIONS'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274152/flask-sqlalchemy-keyerror-sqlalchemy-track-modifications)

Comment: Yes, removing one of the app instances solved the problem. Thanks:)