# Flask throwing exception when i run my app

Tags: python, flask

I started a simple Flask project, i'm using SLQAlchemy to handle my Database. My problem is that every time i run my app, i'll get the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 137, in __init__
    track_modifications = app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']
KeyError: 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'
```

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import json
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.schema import FetchedValue

app = Flask(__name__)

db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'tvtg'}

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(350), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(350), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(350), nullable=False)
    


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    print('HERE')
    peter = User.query.filter_by(name='peter').first()
    print(peter)
    return 'hello_world'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Can anyone help me find what i'm doing wrong? The traceback of the error is not helping me much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask, SQLAlchemy : KeyError: 'SQLALCHEMY\_TRACK\_MODIFICATIONS'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274152/flask-sqlalchemy-keyerror-sqlalchemy-track-modifications)

Comment: I tried that, but still got the same exact error

Comment: If you already tried that and it didnt work, then it sounds like you need to start over again, and add one part at a time until you hit the error again. Then you'll know where the error is coming from and you can add detail to this question.

Comment: In my opinion, this question reads very much like "Here is my code, here is the error, what is wrong?" It doesn't show your effort to identify the issue, which could be accomplished by redoing your code, and identifying exactly when the error gets introduced. Then your question would be "Here is my code, here is the error I'm getting, here is the line in my code that is causing the error to arise, here are the things I've examined that might be the issue, and I'm still stuck."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it looks like when using `flask-sqlalchemy`, you have to set a value for `SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS` - even the documentation says otherwise (defaults to `None`).

Whether you want to set it to `True` or `False` is up to your use case, see documentation

https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/config/

Or have a look at this great tutorial

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database

The unreleased `Flask-Sqlalchemy` version 3 sets a new default of `False`.